# Episerver create page programmatically

Tags: episerver

I am using this code

```
        var parent = ContentReference.StartPage;
        IContentRepository contentRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();

        PageData myPage = contentRepository.GetDefault<LoginPage>(parent);
        myPage.PageName = "My new page";

        var page = contentRepository.GetChildren<LoginPage>(parent).FirstOrDefault(name => name.Name == myPage.Name);

        if (page == null)
            contentRepository.Save(myPage, EPiServer.DataAccess.SaveAction.Publish);
```

to create a page programatically. The thing is I am not sure where to put this code?

I don't want to show LoginPage which is page type to show in the list in the admin/edit panel as I want to create only one page under that page type. Maybe there is another way where I can just create a stand alone page and don't have to create the page type or maybe use an already made page type.

This is the code for my page type

```
[ContentType(DisplayName = "Custom Login Page", GUID = "c0d358c3-4789-4e53-bef3-6ce20efecaeb", Description = "")]
public class LoginPage : StandardPage
{
    /*
            [CultureSpecific]
            [Display(
                Name = "Main body",
                Description = "The main body will be shown in the main content area of the page, using the XHTML-editor you can insert for example text, images and tables.",
                GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
                Order = 1)]
            public virtual XhtmlString MainBody { get; set; }
     */
}
```

Then I am creating a model like this

```
public class LoginModel : PageViewModel<LoginPage>
{
    public LoginFormPostbackData LoginPostbackData { get; set; } = new LoginFormPostbackData();
    public LoginModel(LoginPage currentPage)
        : base(currentPage)
    {
    }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class LoginFormPostbackData
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller looks like this

```
    public ActionResult Index(LoginPage currentPage, [FromUri]string ReturnUrl)
    {

        var model = new LoginModel(currentPage);
        model.LoginPostbackData.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Do you think there is another way to do it? I will also show my login view

```
@using EPiServer.Globalization
@model LoginModel

<h1 @Html.EditAttributes(x => 
x.CurrentPage.PageName)>@Model.CurrentPage.PageName</h1>
<p class="introduction" @Html.EditAttributes(x => 
x.CurrentPage.MetaDescription)>@Model.CurrentPage.MetaDescription</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="span8 clearfix" @Html.EditAttributes(x => 
x.CurrentPage.MainBody)>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CurrentPage.MainBody)

</div>
```

```
@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
!User.IsInRole("rystadEnergyCustomer"))
{
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Post", null, new { language = ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture.Name }))
    {
        <div class="logo"></div>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Log in</h2>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Username, new { @class = "sr-only" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Username, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Password, new { @class = "sr-only" })
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.RememberMe)
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.RememberMe)
            </label>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LoginPostbackData.ReturnUrl, "/login-customers")
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" />
    }
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Message)
</div>
}
else
{
<span>Welcome @User.Identity.Name</span>
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "LoginPage", null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding some of the Episerver concepts.

If you don't want it to be a page in Episerver, you shouldn't use PageController, page types, or templates. Instead, just use a standard controller and view to create your login page.

Otherwise, you do have to create a page of type `LoginPage`, which will be visible in the page tree. No need to create it programmatically, you can just add the page manually and then hide the `LoginPage` type from edit mode to avoid editors creating additional login pages.

Comment: Thanks @Ted I tried creating the normal way or the standard way but then I wasn't able to access it like we do in MVC controller. Maybe I need to create a route mapping for it?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a default route in order to access standard controllers with URLs like `/[Controller]/[Action]`.